# how to check if file exists in docker container then copy it

Tags: docker

I am using docker cp to copy a file in a running container to the host server (in which contains the running docker container) as follows:

```
docker cp $containerId:/tmp/allure-results $WORKSPACE/allure
```

This obviously only works if file exists but sometimes there is a delay until file is created.
How can I make sure if the file exists then copy it and if not wait until it exists and the cp should happen.
something similar to this:

```
if allure exits then 
 docker cp $containerId:/tmp/allure-results $WORKSPACE/allure
else
 wait for 5 second and check again
```

Is it possible?

Comment: A better approach maybe is checking the file through bash and then fire up your container build.

Comment: @PauloPedroso I should have the docker build process running and then the file is created by docker run processes. So inside that container this file will be generated

Comment: A bind mount to make the output directory be an actual host directory is probably an easier solution.

Comment: You can looks torward inotify to react on the file creation https://hub.docker.com/r/coppit/inotify-command/

Comment: @Learner if the whole content of $containerId:/tmp/allure-results and $WORKSPACE/allure are the same, just map them with -v when running the container, this way you don't have to copy the file.

Comment: @Learner otherwise map the $containerId:/tmp/allure-results to another directory and make yout bash script watch for the file creation. This way it would be a simple copy within your hard drive and you won't need to run docker cp.

Comment: @PauloPedroso Can you shed light on this with an example:  $containerId:/tmp/allure-results to another directory. I am a bit confused. So the file gets generated in docker-container and then I need to copy it to the host directory

Comment: @Learner Have you figured this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
docker exec -it $containerId test -f /tmp/allure-results
```

Returns $? as zero if file exists or 1 if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use sh -c to achieve this, and make sure you use double quotes in bash rather than single quotes when substituting variable names:

```
$1=filename
docker exec -it container_id sh -c "test -f /path/to/$1"
file_exists=$?
if [ $file_exists -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Copying file"
  docker cp container_id:/path/to/$1 ./$1
fi
```